# Unable to upgrade postfix from 2.9.6-2 to 3.2.2-1

Tags: debian, apt, postfix

I can't execute `apt-get upgrade` because, I have an error with my `postfix` version.

I am getting the below error if I try to install only the `postfix` package but I don't understand how to resolve this issue?

```
 root@srv-ispconfig:~# apt-get install postfix
    Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
    Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
    Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
    Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
      fontconfig-config fonts-droid fonts-liberation gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme imagemagick-common libcupsimage2 libdatrie1 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libexiv2-12 libfuse2 libgs9-common
      libijs-0.35 libilmbase6 libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblensfun-data liblensfun0 liblqr-1-0 libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpixman-1-0 libthai-data
      libthai0 libtiff4 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxrender1 netpbm poppler-data ufraw-batch
    Veuillez utiliser « apt-get autoremove » pour les supprimer.
    Paquets suggérés :
      postfix-mysql postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap postfix-pcre postfix-lmdb postfix-sqlite sasl2-bin resolvconf postfix-cdb ufw
    Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
      postfix
    1 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 168 non mis à jour.
    2 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
    Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/1 448 ko dans les archives.
    Après cette opération, 471 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
    Lecture des fichiers de modifications (« changelog »)... Terminé
    Préconfiguration des paquets...
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    Use of uninitialized value $destinations in scalar chomp at /tmp/postfix.config.418131 line 221.
    Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    Use of uninitialized value $mynetworks in scalar chomp at /tmp/postfix.config.418131 line 285.
    Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    Use of uninitialized value $protos in scalar chomp at /tmp/postfix.config.418131 line 387.
    Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
    dpkg: avertissement: le fichier contenant la liste des fichiers du paquet « postfix » étant manquant, il est considéré qu'aucun fichier du paquet n'est actuellement installé
    (Lecture de la base de données... 69515 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
    Préparation du dépaquetage de .../postfix_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    Use of uninitialized value $destinations in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/config line 221.
    Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    Use of uninitialized value $mynetworks in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/config line 285.
    Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    Use of uninitialized value $protos in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/config line 387.
    Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
    postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
    dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postfix_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack) :
     le sous-processus nouveau script pre-installation a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
    Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
     /var/cache/apt/archives/postfix_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    root@srv-ispconfig:~#
```

My server version is :

`Linux servername 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.89-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
with ISPconfig3` installed and up to date

I did also tried the below :

- `clear apt-get`
- `purge postfix install`
- Check postfix dependencies and apply update

but, none of them worked for me.

And tried `apt-get -f install` but didn't worked.

```
root@msi-ispconfig:~# clear
root@srv-ispconfig:~# apt-get -f install
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Correction des dépendances... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  fontconfig-config fonts-droid fonts-liberation gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme html2text imagemagick-common libcupsimage2 libdatrie1 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libexiv2-12 libfuse2
  libgs9-common libijs-0.35 libilmbase6 libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblensfun-data liblensfun0 liblqr-1-0 libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libpixman-1-0 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff4 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxrender1 netpbm poppler-data ufraw-batch
Veuillez utiliser « apt-get autoremove » pour les supprimer.
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés :
  postfix
Paquets suggérés :
  postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap postfix-pcre postfix-lmdb postfix-sqlite sasl2-bin resolvconf postfix-cdb ufw
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  postfix
1 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 167 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/1 448 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 471 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer [O/n] ? o
Lecture des fichiers de modifications (« changelog »)... Terminé
Préconfiguration des paquets...
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
Use of uninitialized value $destinations in scalar chomp at /tmp/postfix.config.72701 line 221.
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
Use of uninitialized value $mynetworks in scalar chomp at /tmp/postfix.config.72701 line 285.
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
Use of uninitialized value $protos in scalar chomp at /tmp/postfix.config.72701 line 387.
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
dpkg: avertissement: le fichier contenant la liste des fichiers du paquet « postfix » étant manquant, il est considéré qu'aucun fichier du paquet n'est actuellement installé
(Lecture de la base de données... 69877 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../postfix_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
Use of uninitialized value $destinations in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/config line 221.
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
Use of uninitialized value $mynetworks in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/config line 285.
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
Use of uninitialized value $protos in scalar chomp at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/config line 387.
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Client/ConfModule.pm line 121.
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
postconf: invalid option -- 'x'
postconf: fatal: usage: postconf [-a (server SASL types)] [-A (client SASL types)] [-b (bounce templates)] [-c config_dir] [-C param_class] [-d (defaults)] [-e (edit)] [-f (fold lines)] [-# (comment-out)] [-h (no names)] [-l (lock types)] [-m (map types)] [-M (master.cf)] [-n (non-defaults)] [-v] [name...]
dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postfix_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack) :
 le sous-processus nouveau script pre-installation a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postfix_3.2.2-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@srv-ispconfig:~#
```

This is the output for apt-cache policy postfix ( sorry, in french)

```
postfix:
  Installé : 3.2.2-1
  Candidat : 3.2.2-1
 Table de version :
 *** 3.2.2-1 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.9.6-2 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

Really strange :

i have make a new apt-get update , and apt-get upgrade, and all it's ok, i don't understand why !

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Looks like you have broken repo/packages. Can you please translate the logs to English and paste it again?

Comment: To get the errors in english, you could do `LANGUAGE=en_US apt-get -f install`

Comment: There is no 3.2 version of postfix on Debian Wheezy - https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/postfix - you can upgrade from 2.9 to 2.11 on wheezy-backports - https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy-backports&searchon=names&keywords=postfix . Are you sure you didn't messed your `sources.list` ?

Comment: Do you have a specific repo configured for postfix?

Comment: Hello, i think it's due to a mistake. This server is a wheezy, and nwildner right, I got it wrong i can't update postfix to this version. Now I have to look for the package that requires me to upgrade postfix, uninstall it. And make an update to my linux distribution. Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe add the output of `apt-cache policy postfix` (ideally with English locale so we don't have to grapple over translated messages)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this problem is due to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=848686 where '-x' was added to the preinstall hooks.

I was able to work around it by first upgrading postfix to version 2.11.3-1+deb8u2 from jessie (oldstable), and then to stretch (stable).

Comment: To describe the process in more detail: I downloaded the Jessie package from [packages](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/postfix/download), then issued `dpkg -i postfix_2.11.3-1+deb8u2_amd64.deb` (which failed because of missing dependencies), and then fixed the dependencies by `apt install -f`. Finally, `apt upgrade` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above user has not shared how to do the actual upgrading. This is what I do with problematic packages when I know for sure that the next version fixes a particular issue.

First make a dependency package list and try to upgrade all the dependency packages first, for instance postfix has quite a few depends, conflicts, suggests etc. which means there are choices that you have to make -

```
[$] apt-cache depends postfix                                                                                                       
postfix
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libdb5.3
  Depends: libicu57
  Depends: libsasl2-2
  Depends: libssl1.1
 |Depends: debconf
  Depends: <debconf-2.0>
    cdebconf
    debconf
  Depends: init-system-helpers
  Depends: netbase
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: dpkg
    dpkg:i386
  Depends: lsb-base
  Depends: ssl-cert
  Depends: cpio
    cpio:i386
  Conflicts: <mail-transport-agent>
    citadel-server
    courier-mta
    dma:i386
    dma
    esmtp-run
    exim4-daemon-heavy
    exim4-daemon-light
    masqmail
    msmtp-mta
    nullmailer
    opensmtpd
    qmail-run
    sendmail-bin
    ssmtp
  Conflicts: <smail>
  Recommends: python3
  Suggests: procmail
  Suggests: postfix-mysql
  Suggests: postfix-pgsql
  Suggests: postfix-ldap
  Suggests: postfix-pcre
  Suggests: postfix-lmdb
  Suggests: postfix-sqlite
  Suggests: sasl2-bin
  Suggests: libsasl2-modules
  Suggests: <dovecot-common>
    dovecot-core
  Suggests: resolvconf
    openresolv
  Suggests: postfix-cdb
  Suggests: <mail-reader>
    balsa
    bsd-mailx
    claws-mail:i386
    claws-mail
    edbrowse
    emacs24
    emacs24-lucid
    emacs24-nox
    emacs25
    emacs25-lucid
    emacs25-nox
    evolution
    gnumail.app
    im
    jed
    kmail
    mailutils
    mailutils-mh
    mew
    mew-beta
    mew-beta-bin
    mew-bin
    mmh
    mutt
    nmh
    s-nail
    sup-mail
    sylpheed
    thunderbird
    tkrat
    vm
    wl
    wl-beta
    xemacs21-mule
    xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn
    xemacs21-nomule
    xjed
  Suggests: ufw
  Suggests: postfix-doc
  Replaces: <mail-transport-agent>
    citadel-server
    courier-mta
    dma:i386
    dma
    esmtp-run
    exim4-daemon-heavy
    exim4-daemon-light
    masqmail
    msmtp-mta
    nullmailer
    opensmtpd
    postfix
    qmail-run
    sendmail-bin
    ssmtp
```

I would first take backup of any postfix configuration files, then if possible purge postfix -

```
$ sudo aptitude purge postfix
```

if that works then try to update/upgrade the underlying dependency chain till where it works without an issue.

Then go to the PTR page (Package tracking page) packages.debian.org, download the specific version

```
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/postfix/download
```

Download it from the mirror nearest to you and try to install it via dpkg. DPKG will complain in case some of the dependency are not of the same version. If you have jessie in your in your /etc/apt/sources.list then upgrade to that, if you want to jump directly from wheezy to stretch then download all the dependency packages the way I shared above, do it in shell and be ready for any brokenness which is possible..

There is only golden rule in Debian, don't get panicked and have quite a bit of time to tinker around. If you have a clear mind and time to tinker, then this can be fixed quite easily. Remember to do all your tinkering in a virtual terminal and put X off when doing things like these. Share with us if you get any issues while doing that by raising a new question and give link of the old question so people know where you are coming from. Hope your postfix installation gets fixed. Another thing you could do is also check postfix version release notes for stretch to know what changes were made and if some incompatible changes are there and fix the corresponding config file.